# Problems using uiZoomControls + setPadding

Tags: android, google-maps

After setting map padding in the bottom of the map, the `uiZoomControls` stopped zooming at my target. After zooming in and out a couple of times the old map center is out of the screen.

Is there anyway to fix this or is it a bug in the maps api? The native google map app doesn't even use the `uiZoomControls` :-/

**Example**

Step 1: Focused on the target
[image]

Step 2: Zooms out with the UI controls
[image]

Step 3: Zooms back in with the UI controls, and it's totally off, zooming in to another target than specified. 
[image]

Comment: Can you post sample code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: The map padding is a couple of hundred pixels, the bottom panel slider is covering the bottom part of the map.

Comment: I guess that one solution would be to just get rid of the +/- buttons, not even google is using the buttons.